# ClassNotFoundException while switching to STS 3.8.3

Tags: java, tomcat

This might be a simple question but it's bugging me for two days. So, I am getting `ClassNotFoundException` while deploying my application in local `Tomcat Server`. I get most of the jars from a `Parent Project` and `Maven Install` is successful. The class `StartupListsner` is present inside the app I am trying to deploy but for some reason the compiler is unable to find it. I've done cleaning the project, update Maven project, restart the IDE and clean tomcat directory but no luck. Is there any other way to get rid of this error?

Stack trace:

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class mig.esign.admin.action.listener.StartupListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mig.esign.admin.action.listener.StartupListener
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4854)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
Jan 26, 2017 7:42:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
Jan 26, 2017 7:42:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jan 26, 2017 7:42:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/ESignatureAdmin] startup failed due to previous errors
Jan 26, 2017 7:42:36 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 26, 2017 7:42:36 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 26, 2017 7:42:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 8765 ms
```

Comment: You should have posted the link to the answer too, because I am trying to resolve my issue. Marked as duplicate won't help.

Comment: I've voted to reopen since this is *not* a duplicate. Can you edit the question (title and content) to make the difference obvious for reviewers?

Answer (score -1):

Do you have the following dependency in your `pom.xml` or the `pom.xml` of the parent ?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.echocat.jomon</groupId>
    <artifactId>process</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I don't and I think I don't even need it because the app was starting absolutely fine. This is happening because I switched to a newer version of STS 3.8.3.

Comment: Should I understand that your problem is fixed ? Also the missing class belongs to the dependency I provided : http://snacktrace.com/artifacts/org.echocat.jomon/process/1.6.3/org.echocat.jomon.process.listeners.startup.StartupListener

Comment: The class you are assuming that I am missing is a different class. They got the same name but the look at the package please. The one I am missing is not a third party library.

Comment: Still having the issue.

Comment: Ok. So where this class is comming from ? Your maven project or parent project or ... ?

Comment: Maven Project. Not from the Parent.